# Ограничить вывод количества полей ACF Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, acf

Использую галерею в плагине Advanced Custom Fields.
Вывожу изображения таким образом. 
Мне нужно ограничить количество выводимых изображений (полей), как это сделать? 
Нужно выводить последние 3 добавленных...

Буду благодарен за помощь.

```html
<?php 

$images = get_field('gallery');

if( $images ): ?>
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
    <li>
      <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
      <p>
        <?php echo $image['caption']; ?>
      </p>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
    <li>
      <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: я бы использовал `acf repeater` или `posts_per_page`

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count($images)-1;

$limit = $count-3; 

<?php for($i = $count; $i > $limit; $i--): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $images[$i]['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images[$i]['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endfor; ?>
```